# When is the Fitting subgroup of a group trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The Fitting subgroup of a group is defined as the subgroup generated by all the nilpotent normal subgroups of the group.

One criteria that I've just read about is that semisimple groups (without a non-trivial normal abelian subgroup) have a trivial Fitting subgroup. How is this so?

Comment: Which definition of the Fitting subgroup have you seen? Which normal subgroups does $S_n$ have?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $Fit(G)$ is the subgroup generated by all of the nilpotent normal subgroups. And $A_n$ is the only normal subgroup, which is not nilpotent. Yes I see now how the fitting subgroup is trivial of $S_n$. But what about the general situation?

Comment: The Fitting subgroup is trivial precisely when the group has no non-trivial normal nilpotent subgroup. There might be a more useful criterion, but I am not familiar with one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I've found that semisimple groups are also Fitting free. I've edited my question now.

Comment: A nontrivial normal nilpotent subgroup will have a nontrivial center, which is normal in the full group (since it is characteristic in the subgroup). So any group with a nontrivial Fitting subgroup will have a nontrivial normal abelian subgroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you so much for your help.